# Select query to get locked tables

Tags: mysql

How to determine what are the tables locked using mysql?

Comment: Is there any way to implement this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SHOW OPEN TABLES to show each table's lock status. More details on the command's doc page are here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-open-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, **show open tables where `Name_locked`=1;** will get what you want.